# Is it OK to use "type" as a variable name?

Tags: javascript, reserved-words

```
let type = "HI";

console.log(type)
```

I know its not a reserved word but its showing in blue color while taking as a variable so got a doubt?

Comment: If you are not facing any **specific** problem, what keeps you from using that code?

Comment: I can't find `type` from the [list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#keywords).

Comment: The "blue" color comes from your development environment. type is not a reserved word in js, so you can use it.

Comment: "its showing in blue color" just like EVERY variable name

Answer (score 1):

Per this documentation, `type` is not reserved word for now or near future.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar

Note that `typeof` is reserved word. So, it is a matter of readability and naming conventions that you/your team may follow.